# Implode on ampersand, PHP

Tags: php

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong on how to implode an array on an ampersand using PHP? I am trying to send a string in AJAX that comes from this array; and nothing I am trying is working ->

```
$mrq = (implode("&",$mrqa));
```

is yielding

```
macro0=A¯o1=B
```

However, I was expecting it to yield

```
macro0=A&macro1=B
```

Is there a way to get around this? I am using UTF-8, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: To build query you should use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: Problem not in implode, problem in output. Use `htmlspecialchars` or see output in plain text, not in html.

Comment: Ensure that you're displaying as UTF-8 if your $mrqa string values are UTF-8

Comment: @OZ_ +1 You are correct - this is because browser is interpreting part of the string as HTML entity. It displays `&macr` as `¯`. Look for `&macr;` on [this page](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html).

Comment: @OZ_ Please post an answer ;) You just answered the question and there is no 'upvote comment as an answer' button...

Comment: yeah, what @Robik said -- you don't need to do all that hard work; PHP has a perfectly good built-in function for building query strings. http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Answer (score 1):

Problem not in implode, problem in output, because `&macr` is a html entity.
Use `htmlspecialchars` or see output in plain text, not in html.
Also, as mentioned in comments, to build your request you can use the [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform each param before put in url.

```
foreach($mrqa as $key => $m)
$mrqa[$key] = urlencode($m);

$mrq = implode("&",$mrqa);
```